# Error of InverseFunction

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

## Update

This bug has been fixed in v11.3.0.
And as @Carl Woll has pointed out, the imaginary part of `Sin` and negative sign of `Cos` are due to the selections of different branch cuts.

## Original Post

v11.2.0.0 on Windows 10, 64bit, check this:

```
InverseFunction /@ {f[#] &, f[2 #] &, f[#/2] &, f[# + 1] &} 
/. {{f -> Sinh}, {f -> Cosh}, {f -> Tanh}, {f -> Coth}} // TableForm
```

The result is only correct for `Coth` case;
`Sinh` picks up an imaginary part, 
`Cosh` adds an negative sign, 
`Tanh` entangles with `ArcCoth` instead of `ArcTanh`.

[image]

This is really a disturbing error. Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The results for `Sinh` and `Cosh` are not incorrect. All of your functions have multi-valued inverses, so you're seeing Mathematica choose different branches than you were expecting. For example:

```
x = Sinh[2 3.]
y = 1/2 (I Pi - ArcSinh[#])&[x]
Sinh[2 y]
```

> 201.713
>
> -3. + 1.5708 I
>
> 201.713 + 2.4703*10^-14 I

If you want to restrict to real inverses, you could use [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression):

```
if = InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[Sinh[2 #], # ∈ Reals]&];
```

Then:

```
if[Sinh[2 3.]]
```

> 3.

On the other hand, I do think the results for `Tanh` are incorrect. It would be worth reporting the issue to support. In particular, I think the following demonstrates the issue:

```
if = InverseFunction[Tanh[2#]&]

x = Tanh[2 .1`30]
y = if[x]
Tanh[2 y]
```

> InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses.
>
> ArcCoth[#1]/2 &
>
> 0.197375320224904000738157318811
>
> 0.100000000000000000000000000000 - 0.785398163397448309615660845820 I
>
> 5.0664895634394727136317877883 + 0.*10^-30 I

The output of `Tanh[2 y]` should be the same as `x`. Again, you can work around the issue by including a [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) wrapper:

```
if = InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[Tanh[2#], # ∈ Reals]&]

x = Tanh[2 .1`30]
y = if[x]
Tanh[2 y]
```

> ConditionalExpression[ArcTanh[#1]/2, -1 < #1 < 1] &
>
> 0.197375320224904000738157318811
>
> 0.100000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0.197375320224904000738157318811

Comment: Thanks. But what about `Tanh` etc?

Comment: @luyuwuli See update. I do think you found an issue with `Tanh`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've already report this issue to the official feedback.